# Mysql workbench - create user with standard password

Tags: authentication, mysql-workbench

I have updated mysql workbench to 8.0.12,
And I have a big issue with the user management.

Some application do not support SHA2 authentication and I struggle finding a way to use standard one.

In previous version I could easily create user with different type of authentication (standard / caching_sha2_password).

Some advises will be really appreciated.
Downgrade to previous version would be last option.

[image: authentication setting]

[edit]
 when creating the user I can select standard mode. But as soon I apply the creation, it automatically switch to caching_sha2_password
[/edit]
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the default_authentication_method of the server. You can either manually edit the config file and add the following:

```
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Or you can update the options file through MySQL Workbench by going to Server > Options File >

[image]

You will then need to restart the server and recreate your user with the required authentication plugin.

You can read more [here](https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-default-authentication-plugin-considerations/).

Comment: Thanks, I just saw your post but this is exactly what the solution I come with. F1 helped me :p